# Import/Merge a particular column with data from one data table to another

Tags: vb.net, import, merge, datatable

I want to merge or import a column of data from one data table created in VB.NET to another data table's 'same-named' column.
The destination data table has all the required columns created before hand but the source data table contains one column at a time, whose name is the same as that of one of the columns in destination data table.
Whatever coding I have done for the same till now, results in blank rows at starting. The destination data table looks like this:

[image]

And I want it to be displayed it as:

[image]

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I worked out a way around this.
I store all the details in an 2-D array and then used that array as the data source for the grid. So instead of merging tables, keep storing different values in different columns of array.
There might be better solutions to this problem but this solution worked for me.